# Groovy parse xml

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy, parsexml

I'm a newbie in groovy
Can anyone help to parse this xml in order to get a list of values of the each num element

```
 NAMES>
    <NAMESet fetchSize="3">
    <String StringNumber="1">
        <NUM>1</NUM>
    </String>
    <String StringNumber="2">
        <NUM>2</NUM>
    </String>
    <String StringNumber="3">
        <NUM>3</NUM>
</NAMESet>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, [google is your friend](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=groovy%20parse%20xml). Did you tried the [first link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper)? It is the official doc for groovy and xml. If you got problems with that, post some info on what happened.

Comment: Also that XML looks pretty broken. Is that the problem?

Comment: Also show us your code so far

Comment: yeah, I've checked that. I coudn't catch how to get a value of one of the NUM nodes

Comment: Post the code you tried

Comment: there is just one line: def records = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, wrote like this:

```
def records = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
def size = records.ResultSet.Row.ID.size()
println(size)
def allRecords = records.ResultSet.Row.ID[1].text()
println(allRecords)
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
println(records.ResultSet.Row.ID[i].text())
}
```

anyway, thanks

Comment: But that is not even the same XML you posted in your question

Comment: yeah, the same idea here

Answer (score 0):

The XML is pretty broken, but [cyberneko](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) can solve that. It builds up some HTML structure, though:

```
xml=''' NAMES>
    <NAMESet fetchSize="3">
    <String StringNumber="1">
        <NUM>1</NUM>
    </String>
    <String StringNumber="2">
        <NUM>2</NUM>
    </String>
    <String StringNumber="3">
        <NUM>3</NUM>
</NAMESet>'''


names = new XmlSlurper( new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser() ).parseText xml

assert names.BODY.NAMESET.STRING.NUM.collect { it.text() } == 
    ['1', '2', '3']
```